# Como ativar e desativar plugins conforme o Workspace no Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, plugin, workspace

Eu uso o Eclipse para praticamente tudo em meu ambiente de trabalho, sei que muitos irão criticar tal escolha, mas esta não é a questão, tenho diversos Workspace criados, um para programar em C/C++ para ARM outro para C/C++ genérico, outro C/C++ para AVR, mais um para programar em PHP e outro para programar em Java-EE e ainda mais um para Android.

Até já tentei manter versões do Eclipse para cada workspace, mas chega uma hora que atualizar tudo me cansa, e sempre fica mais bagunçado. Fora a perda de espaço e tempo de download.

Estou tendo sucesso razoável em usar o Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) com diversos plugins para cada linguagem citada funcionando com sucesso. Porém uma coisa me chateia, a quantidade de tipos de projetos que posso usar, e as vezes um plugin do JBoss me incomoda quando estou usando o Workspace para programar para ARM, sem dúvida não vou precisar dele neste momento.

Como faço então para desabilitar um ou outro plugin conforme o Workspace que estou usando, o Eclipse Luna já tem este recurso?